# xsl:call-template within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I'm really new at coding, sorry if any of this sounds silly or stupid.  We have a new project to come up with a new webpage.  I have a multiple condition if statement and would like to call a xsl template if condition is met. Here's how I have it now and it doesn't work at all.

```
<script>
function getSelectedValue()
{
if("document.getElementById('type').value==1 and document.getElementById('cablegroup5').value==9"+
"document.getElementById('cablegroup3').value==22 and document.getElementById('cablelength').value==11")
{
<xsl:call-template name="PN">
<xsl:with-param name="Cable">ABC111-06</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
}
}
</script>
```

I know the first part works, I've tested it with an alert message and that works just fine.  These are all activated by a button(onclick) next to multiple drop down menus.  Is there a way to get this to work?  Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The clause in your if statement will always evaluate to `true` as you are passing a string. You are not actually testing for the nodes. Are you wanting to execute the transform against the webpage or do you have a seperate xml document? If you are performing the transform against the document represented by `document` then could you not accomplish the same using JavaScript DOM?

Comment: I have a separate xml document.  I'd like to call the info attached to ABC111-06 that's in my access database.  The if statement comes from the drop down menu selections.  If 1st drop down menu has value of 1, 2nd drop down menu has value of 9, 3rd drop down has value of 22, and 4th drop down has value of 11, then display text from database @ ABC111-06.  I'll look into JavaScript DOM, sorry like I mentioned before I'm pretty new to all of this.  Thanks.

Comment: From the point of view of an XSLT transformation, this is just text surrounding a named template invocation. From the point of view of a browser I don't think that those XSLT elements are valid javascript code. If you want to run a transformation **from javascript code** you need to know how to invoque your XSLT processor. In XSLT 1.0 there is no information in the execution context about a starting named template. In XSLT 2.0 that information is precense but how to declare that depends on the XSLT processor API. You might be interestin in beta Saxon javascript XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Don't apologise for being new to JavaScript. You have at least attempted to do it yourself. When learning JS I found [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) very useful. I have posted a code example as an answer below. It is more complicated than I had initially expected so post a response if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused about the processing model. Is the script element generated by XSLT? If so, the call-template will probably be called at the time the script is generated. It won't be called at the time the script is executed. Javascript code isn't going to magically execute XSLT instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issue within the script that would prevent the `if` statement executing correctly.

1. The boolean and operator in JavaScript is `&&` not `and`. Note the if you use `&` this would be a bitwise and.
2. The tests should not be a string. Due to JavaScript type coersion it a string will be converted to a boolean. A `null` or empty string `''` will evaluate `false`, all other strings will evaluate `true`. Currently you have

   ```
   if("test1 and test2")
   ```

   This should be

   ```
   if(test1 && test2)
   ```

So far your updated script would be

```
<script>
  function getSelectedValue()
  {
  if(document.getElementById('type').value==1 && 
    document.getElementById('cablegroup5').value==9 &&
    document.getElementById('cablegroup3').value==22 &&  
    document.getElementById('cablelength').value == 11)
    {
      // Process Xml
    }
  }
</script>
```

You need to use the browser xml parser to handle your xml. I will assume that you have an xml string, if you have a document object then you will have to change the following slightly, this is from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp).

```
  var xmlString = "<Products>" +
                    "<Product partnumber='foo'>This is product 1</Product>" +
                    "<Product partnumber='bar'>This is product 2</Product>" +
                  "</Products>";
  // Load into an XML document
  var myDoc;
  if (window.DOMParser)
  {
    var parser=new DOMParser();
    myDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
  }
  else // Internet Explorer
  {
    myDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    myDoc.async="false";
    myDoc.loadXML(xmlString);
  }

  // Get all product nodes
  var products = myDoc.getElementsByTagName('Product');
  var i, targetProduct, partNumber;

  for(i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1){
    // Get the partnumber attribute
    partnumber = products[i].attributes.getNamedItem('partnumber');

    // Ensure that the partnumber exists and its value is what is wanted
    if(partnumber && partnumber.value == 'foo'){
      targetProduct = products[i];
      // Exit for
      break;
    }
  }

  // If the product has been found alert its value.
  if(targetProduct != null){
    alert(targetProduct.textContent || targetProduct.text);
  }
```

If you were selected a node by id then you could use `xmlDoc.getElementById` instead of iterating through all nodes of a type and checking attributes.

To select the text value of an xml node most browsers use the property `textContent` although Internet Explorer uses `text`. The line

```
  targetProduct.textContent || targetProduct.text
```

returns `textContent` if it is present and not null, or the value of `text`.

Comment: Wow I may be way over my head here, I didn't really expect it to be that complicated.  I'll have to study what you've provided, you've been most helpful.  I first tried &&, I ended up using and(ie "test1 and test2") because when I use ampersand, it says "Character '&', hexadecimal value 0x26 is illegal in an XML name."  When I tested "and", it worked so I resumed.  I'm very familiar with w3schools, I'm practically on it a couple hours a day trying to figure this out.  Thanks again

Comment: @Charles. Is your script within a HTML document? The error about `&` in an XML name sounds strange. Something that I have had when using xslt and xpath in the past but not with JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I guess I should have included that huh - It's on a .xsl.  I had to use "and" as an escape key

Comment: @Charles. I guess I assumed that it was in HTML due to you mentioning select elements. I haven't used JS within an xsl personally but looking through examples they seem to require an extension namespace and `lang="javascript"` attribute on the script tag. I have looked at an [apache example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipxsltjs/) and a [Microsoft example](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=482). It may be worth trying to wrap the javascript within a CDATA section so that it is not parsed as XML.